# Is it worth to create a generic shader for handling objects with and without textures?

Tags: textures, transparency, shader, opengl-3, depth

I have several object to render. Some of them have textures and some of them are transparent.

To achieve transparency, I implemented the depth peeling tecnique.

I was wondering if I could use just a single shader (for each step, init/peel/blen/final) that handles objects with texture and objects without.

My idea was something like that (init):

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;

in vec2 oUV;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform int enableTexture;

uniform float alpha;

vec4 ShadeFragment() {
    vec4 color;
    color.rgb = vec3(.4,.85,.0);
    color.a = alpha;
    return color;
}

void main(void)
{
    vec4 color = ShadeFragment();

    color = (1 - enableTexture) * color + enableTexture * texture(texture0, oUV);

    outputColor = vec4(color.rgb * color.a, 1.0 - color.a);
}
```

If enableTexture is 1 I grab the result from the texture, if it is 0 I dont evaluate it at all. I wrote that in order to avoid branching.

Is it worth/has sense an approach like this?